# Where to save user setting in an Office365 app

Tags: office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an app for Office365 (to be specific for Outlook) and I am having a question about where to keep the user settings.

This app is targeted for web version of Office365 as a result I hosted on a server. A user of Office365 can go to the store and install the app. However before s/he can use the app, s/he has to set a few fields to be able to use the add-on.

I am not sure if there is a way to keep the settings for a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RoamingSetting](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/RoamingSettings.html) object API to save private data for your Addin for each user.

```
// Get the current value of the 'myKey' setting
var value = Office.context.roamingSettings.get('myKey');

// Update the value of the 'myKey' setting
Office.context.roamingSettings.set('myKey', 'Hello World!');

// Persist the change
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync();
```

For more information, look at the documentation link provided above.

If you instead want to save data for your Addin for an email/calendar item (instead of for an entire mailbox), look at the [CustomProperties](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/CustomProperties.html) object API.

Comment: Cool idea, I didn't know that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess since the app is hosted on my own server, and on the other hand, the user is already authenticated, I can keep the settings per some unique feature of user, e.g. username, by conventional methods in the server.